# Looking for a Windows 8 XAML control that can contain a clipped animated image in it

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing Windows store apps. In one of the apps, instead of having image controls, I would like to have container controls that display single animated images from within (Similar to the News Bento app welcome screen on Windows 8). The closest I have come to that is AnimatingContainer control from WinRT XAML toolkit, but it doesn't seem to work with images (At least in my case). Any help on how to use this control to animate an image or any other solution will be grateful. Below is my XAML code. If I uncomment the text block and comment the image, the text block is displayed animated. But the reverse isn't true.

```
<Controls1:AnimatingContainer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="311" Margin="163,23,0,0" RadiusX="25"
            RadiusY="10"
            Duration="0:0:10" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="461">  
        <!--<TextBlock Text="Sume Rossini" FontSize="66"/>-->
        <Image Source="Assets/Davy_Jones.jpg" Width="300" Height="500"/>
    </Controls1:AnimatingContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There likely isn't any. You would need to write one yourself to fit your specific requirements. Use Blend to create the animation. Ask more specific questions and you may get help implementing it.

Comment: I did what u said and used Blend. The control works fine. I had problems data binding the the image in the user control to an ImageSource but later solved it using dependency property. Thanks a lot